# MyBatis mapper interface retain column order in List of Maps

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Using MyBatis (3.5.5) and Mybatis-Spring (2.0.5), I have a mapper interface as follows:

```
public interface BillingMapper{

   @Select("SELECT * FROM bi.manager_view WHERE bill_id = ${bill_id}")
   public LinkedList<Map<String, Object>> managerView(@Param("bill_id") Integer bill_id);
```

When I query `manager_view` in psql, the column order is `bill_id, month, total,` whereas the order of the Maps in the List returned from this query is `month, total, bill_id`.  How can I configure the Mapper so that the order of returned columns is maintained?

Comment: I would guess that the `Map` is instantiated as a `HashMap`. Probably the solution is to  instantiated as a `LinkedHashMap` instead, but this is just a guess. I don't think there's any way you could control this on your side. One workaround is to use a bona fide VO instead of a Map (generated from the table).

Comment: As you suggested, simply changing the Return type of the method resulted in correctly ordered columns, i.e.`public LinkedList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>`